# SQL, How to create series of dates between given two dates?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Suppose you have a cron-like expression

`2:30 every monday and wednesday` and a period `2020.05.23 - 2021.02.02`

I want to create a row for every matching time in the period

```
2:30 2020.05.25 (mon)
2:30 2020.05.27 (wed)
```

How to create them in batches?

(I'm on postgresql, django if it matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the timestamps you want you can use following query

```
select d from
    generate_series('2020.05.23 2:30:00'::timestamp, '2021.02.02 2:30:00'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) d
where extract(dow from d) in (1,3)
```

To insert into table in batch

```
Insert into <table_name> (<column_name>)
select d from
    generate_series('2020.05.23 2:30:00'::timestamp, '2021.02.02 2:30:00'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) d
where extract(dow from d) in (1,3)
```